# Unable to reflect JSON in grid

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geoext, ext-js

I am trying to fetch the data from JSON and display it onto the grid. The `store` has all the JSON data, but I it is not visible in the Grid. The grid comes out completely blank.

This is the application, `http://128.196.142.12/geo/test/test_new.html`, select the `Bioclim Data` tool from the toolbar, on the top right and then click on the map.

Here is the entire code,

```
action = new GeoExt.Action({
        text: "BioClim Data",
        control: new OpenLayers.Control.Click({
             //control.events.on({"click": function(evt) {
                 trigger: function(evt) {
                      var lonLat = evt.xy;
                      var proj = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
                      var nlonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(panel.map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(lonLat).lon, panel.map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(lonLat).lat);
                      nlonLat.transform(panel.map.getProjectionObject(), panel.map.displayProjection);
                      if (popup) popup.close();
                      var  request = Ext.Ajax.request({
                      url:"/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=http://128.196.142.12:9000/info?lat="+ nlonLat.lat +"&lon="+ nlonLat.lon,
                      disableCaching: false,
                      success: function(response) {
                              var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                              var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                              //console.dir(obj);
                              store = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
                                  layer: features,
                                  fields: jsonData,
                                  autoLoad: true
                              });
                              addToPopup(lonLat, response.responseText);

                              var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    title: "BioClim Table",
                    store: store,
                    width: 600,
                    height: 250,
                    stripeRows: true,
                    columns: [{
                        header: "Annual Mean Temperature",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "mat"
                    }, {
                        header: "Mean Diurnal Range",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "mdr"
                    }, {
                        header: "Isothermality",
                        width: 100,
                        dataIndex: "iso"
                    }, {
                        header: "Temperature Seasonality",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "tsd"
                    }, {
                        header: "Max Temperature of Warmest Month",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "maxtwm"
                    }, {
                        header: "Min Temperature of Coldest Month",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "anntmin"
                    }, {
                        header: "Temperature Annual Range",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "tar"
                    }, {
                        header: "Mean Temperature of Wettest Quarter",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "meantwq"
                    }, {
                        header: "Mean Temperature of Driest Quarter",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "meantdq"
                    }, {
                        header: "Mean Temperature of Warmest Quarter",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "meantwaq"
                    }, {
                        header: "Mean Temperature of Coldest Quarter",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "meantcq"
                    }, {
                        header: "Annual Precipitation",
                        width: 150,
                        dataIndex: "annprec"
                    }, {
                        header: "Precipitation of Wettest Month",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "precwm"
                    }, {
                        header: "Precipitation of Driest Month",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "precdm"
                    }, {
                        header: "Precipitation Seasonality",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "precs"
                    }, {
                        header: "Precipitation of Wettest Quarter",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "precwq"
                    }, {
                        header: "Precipitation of Driest Quarter",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "precdq"
                    }, {
                        header: "Precipitation of Warmest Quarter",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "precwarmq"
                    }, {
                        header: "Precipitation of Coldest Quarter",
                        width: 200,
                        dataIndex: "preccq"
                    }],
                    //sm: new GeoExt.grid.FeatureSelectionModel()
                    listeners: {render:function(grid){
                        grid.getSelectionModel().selectFirstRow();
                    }}
                });

                /*var exportCSV = new Ext.ux.Exporter.Button({
                                  component: grid,
                                  text : 'Download CSV'
                              });

                              grid.getTopToolbar().add(exportCSV);*/

                              var win = new Ext.Window({
                                  width: 600,
                                  height: 300,
                                  autoScroll: true,
                                  title: "BioClim Data",
                                  /*tbar: [{
                                    text: 'Download CSV',
                                    handler: new Ext.ux.Exporter.Button({
                                        //alert('Downloads the CSV');
                                        component: grid
                                    })  
                                  }],*/
                                  listners:{show:function() {
                                      this.loadMask = new Ext.LoadMask(this.body, {
                                           msg:'Loading. Please wait...'
                                      });
                                   }},
                                   items: grid        
                            });
                            win.show();
                          },
                      failure: function(response) {
                              console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
                              addToPopup(lonLat, "Server side Failure");
                          }  
                             //callback: myhandler
                 });
             }}),
        map: map,
        // button options
        toggleGroup: "draw",
        allowDepress: false,
        tooltip: "Fetch BioClim Data",
        // check item options
        group: "newTool"
    });
    actions["bioclim"] = action;
    toolbarItems.push(action);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only suppose to change the JSON format to bind to the store. I was using JSON as `[var1, var2, var3]` but the correct format is `[[var1], [var2], [var3]]`

Answer (score 2):

I think mistake in your store. You not determinete fields but try to get it in your columns. Try this

```
 store = new Ext.data.Store({
url: '<your_servlet_url>',
reader: new Ext.data.JSONReader({
        record: 'kad', //its your json record name
        fields: [
            {name: 'kad_status', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'kad_id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'kad_name', type: 'string'}
        ]
    })
});
```

Its simplest method. If you want to get server response in another place i should parse your JSON to get a fields.

Comment: but on `Ext.Ajax.request`, I already passed the `url`. Should I pass the same `url` again?

Comment: In my example you not need `Ext.Ajax.request` for create store. Store can himself get JSON (or XML) from server. But if you need in `Ext.Ajax.request` you can use it, then parse your JSON and create array then use ArrayStore http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Store .

Comment: I added the following,

`var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);`
`store = new Ext.data.Store({
       fields: jsonData
      });`

The firebug shows the fields and the data in there, but still it is not reflected in the grid.

Any idea where I am going wrong? :(

This is the app link http://128.196.142.12/geo/test/test_new.html

Comment: Oh i think i understand where I am falling short. The `jsonData` contains the fields and the data. So how can I separate the jsonData -> field and assign it to `fields:` and jsonData -> data and assign it to `data:`. This is how my `jsonData` looks, `{"preccq": 240, "annprec": 877, "meantwaq": 116, "mat": 16, "tar": 356, "precs": 16, "tsd": 7994, "precwm": 89, "precwq": 253, "meantcq": -88, "maxtwm": 200, "anntmin": -156, "precwarmq": 243, "iso": 33, "meantdq": 13, "mdr": 120, "precdq": 170, "meantwq": -82, "precdm": 47}`

Comment: I watch to your application and see you dont want to determinate data fields. Okey anyway i dont see your grid. In my example JSON parse automaticaly, but if you want do its by a hands, just work with it like a string. Its not a problem. And i see that you try make app on ExtJs+GeoExt, you try a gxp http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/examples/viewer.html?